# R - bare to quosure in function - invalid argument type

Tags: r, function, dplyr

I get a *"Error in !x : invalid argument type"* error when I run the code below. It looks pretty correct to me. Hmm... what went wrong? I just don't know.

```
library(tidyverse)
addition_function <- function(x, y) {
  x <- enquo(x)
  y <- enquo(y)
  z <- (!!x) + (!!y)
  z
}

a <- 2
b <- 7
addition_function(a, b)
```

Comment: `addition_function <- function(x, y) {
  z <- x + y
  z
}` is sufficient. No need for `enquo` unless you are working with some `dplyr` functions.

Comment: @www Thanks for the input. But I'm more interested why it *doesn't* work. I thought that's how Tidy Eval worked with `enqou()` and bang bang `!!`. Why doesn't it work? I'm trying to start with the simplest examples to teach myself and the first one already breaks! ahhh!

Comment: @stackinator: tidy evaluation is for the tidyverse/dplyr verbs only. That should not work with base R the way you wrote in that function. Try to unquote `!!x` and `!!y` inside dplyr verbs and it should work

Comment: btw I think outside of the tidyverse framework, `!` means negation so `!!` equals to double negation